# How to split chinese and english word once only?

Tags: python, string

I am using Python and I would like to split the following string:

```
string = '小西 - 杏花 Siu Sai - Heng Fa'
```

I would like to split the string that could give me `小西 - 杏花` and `Siu Sai - Heng Fa`. I tried different ways and still couldn't split the string properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many trivial answers, like splitting after the 7th character and before the 9th, or splitting over spaces and rejoining cleverly. What is the pattern here? Is the pattern "chinese characters with other symbols followed by english characters with other symbols"?

Comment: I have a multiple strings with the same pattern. Therefore I couldn't split the string using the fixed character method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the option is just to split before the first English character and take the 1st and 2nd group

```
inputstring = '小西 - 杏花 Siu Sai - Heng Fa'
a = re.split(r'([a-zA-Z].*)', inputstring)
>>>['小西 - 杏花 ', 'Siu Sai - Heng Fa', '']
```

Another way to do this without an empty string is to use the regex `?=[a-z]` as pointed out by @blhsing

```
a = re.split(r'(?:=[a-z])', inputstring)
```

Comment: Use `re.split(r'(?=[a-z])', flags=re.I)` to produce the desired list without an empty string.

Comment: Updated with your feedback as another way!

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern you're looking for is "a series of non-alphabetical characters, followed by a space, followed by a series of alphabetical characters, spaces and dashes":

```
import re

text = '小西 - 杏花 Siu Sai - Heng Fa'

m = re.match(r'([^a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z\s-]+)', text)
print(f'"{m.group(1)}"')
print(f'"{m.group(2)}"')
```

Output:

```
"小西 - 杏花"
"Siu Sai - Heng Fa"
```

So, `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)` will be the parts of the string you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with other string and it doesn't work on the brackets. I still appreciate your answer. =)